# How to set h2 tag to it's default size

Tags: html, css

The font size of my root element is 16px. I am trying to get set my h2 tag to its normal default size.

CSS of the h2 declaration:

```css
.cursive {
  font-family: "Damion", cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-up-section" class="banner">
  <div id="sign-up-cta">
    <div class="content center">
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
        <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
      </div>
```

The font size of my root element is 16px of the HTML declaration inside my CSS.

When I added the rem value to increase the font size of the font, the code disappears and does not show the font of the h2 class which is called cursive.

However, when I deleted the class and cursive text till it just shows h2, the h2 shows the font and any other fonts that are h2 tags in its default size, which is not what I want as I want the class cursive, font size to change to its default size.

At first, I changed the font size normally using pixels, the font size increased but only up 22px maximum but not anything further than that.

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Cursive font color is set to white

Comment: only change the color of the h2 from white to another color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the color of h2 tag (cursive class) is set to white!

So write like this:

```css
.cursive {
  font-family: "Damion", cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3rem;    
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-up-section" class="banner">
      <div id="sign-up-cta">
        <div class="content center">
          <div class="header">
            <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
            <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
          </div>
```

Now you can see changes

Comment: Hi Ali, it worked, the font size changed to the size I wanted. But I realised that it was the positioning code that prevented it from showing so I put the postion code back but deleted the transform: translate code. Which worked so thank you so so much.